# Pass PHP variable to .js file (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Let's say i have a variable in a php-file (index.php):

```
$PHP_variable = "string";
```

And i want to pass it to my JS file (functions.js) that's currently being read within the php-file. Is that possible?

For example, i have this in my php-file:

```
 <input type="text" name="textfield" value="'.$PHP_variable.'" />
 <input type="button" id="actionButton" />
```

And in the js-file:

```
$('#actionButton').click(function(){
 alert(THE_PHP_VARIABLE);
});
```

How is it possible to pass $PHP_variable to the js file? I'd prefer not to use the js code directly on the php-script (i know how to solve it that way).

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Please use [a search engine](http://google.com) before asking questions.

Comment: @SLaks i know but the data doesn't need to be protected in any way.

Comment: @user2994294: Unless your entire site has nothing remotely sensitive, an XSS vulnerability is still a big problem.

Comment: @Anonymous i did, but couldn't find anything relevant. Oh as i mentioned, **I'd prefer not to use the js code directly on the php-script**, which is what you just linked me

Comment: @user2994294 If you do not want to do that, you need to explain why.  Just saying that the correct solution will not work is not enough.

Comment: If you are happy with answers, thumbs up! :P

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're thinking of using PHP to generate Javascript, which is possible although it's a bit odd.  It's also curious that you really aren't passing the variable, you're using it to render a javascript variable of the same value.

Instead, I think what you'd really want to do is use JS to read the variable from the HTML element's `value` attribute, since you're already storing the variable's value there.

This can be done a lot of ways, but since it looks like you're using jQuery it'd just be:

```
$('#actionButton').click(function(){
  $value = $this.attr('value');
  alert($value);
});
```

Comment: #actionButton doesn't have attribute 'value'. When you have error: $this will not work, you probably meant $(this)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there -

```
$('#actionButton').click(function(){
    var THE_PHP_VARIABLE = $('input[name="textfield"]').val();
    alert(THE_PHP_VARIABLE);
});
```

Since the value is echo'd out when the page loads you can get that quite easily by using `val()` on the correct element.

If you want to assigned variables at the time the page is loaded you could also do this in your PHP -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
   echo "var THE_PHP_VARIABLE = " . $PHP_variable .";";
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, i chose to use a hidden input field with an id and the php-variable as the value for this input, then in the js-file i simply get the val() from this hidden input

```
$input_val = $('#hiddenInputID').val();
```